# Check for existence and assign

Tags: php, array

Is there a smarter way to do the following without the `$result` variable and without the if-statements?

```
    ...
    $description = BIG ARRAY
    $result = array('error' => '', 'amounts' => array(5, 10, 25, 50));
    if (isset($description['error'])) $result['error'] = $description['error'];
    if (isset($description['amounts'])) $result['amounts'] = $description['amounts'];

    return $result;
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to do? $result has defaults that you're trying to overwrite with values from $description if they exist and are non-null? Are error and amounts the only fields?

Comment: @Corbin: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

To see if an array has a specific index you should use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) rather than `isset`.

In case you want default values, how about just assigning all the defaults at the same time:

```
$foo = function_call();
$result = array('error' => (array_key_exists('error', $description) ? $description['error'] : ''), ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the in_array. I thought thats internally the same as isset(). But the function_call() call does not work this way. Where do I put the in_array/isset check? It returned bool, not the element.

Comment: $a = false || 7; echo $a; gives me "true". I think, the boolean operators here are handled the wrong way. I use  PHP 5.4.16

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work this way"? And the point of the code was to avoid the check completely.

Comment: Fixed [syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: You removed the boolean operator and now Its the same as above with a tenary operator :( I hoped there are a solution (like the |= in other languages) to avoid the if condition.

Comment: Looks like there isn't, according to the link above. But this at least removes some duplication.

Comment: `in_array` does not do what you think it does. You're thinking of `array_key_exists`. `in_array` searches for a value, not a key. Also, `array_key_exists` and `isset` are not equivalent. (`isset($arr[$key]) === array_key_exists($key, $arr) && $arr[$key] !== null`)